# URL builder always redirect to dashboard

Tags: magento2, urlbuilder

I've enabled secret key and use url builder to generate edit product and customer link for Magento 2 Backend like this for my custom grid:

```
public function __construct( 
   ...
   UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
   ...
) { 
   ...
   $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
   ...
}

public function setCustomerEditLink($customerId,$customerName){
  $editUrl = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('customer/index/edit/', ['id' => $customerId]);
  $url = '<a href="'.$editUrl.'">' . $customerName . '</a>';
  return $url;
}

public function getProductEditLink($productId,$productName){
  $editUrl = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('customer/index/edit/', ['id' => $customerId]);
  $url = '<a href="'.$editUrl.'">' . $productName . '</a>';
  return $url;
}
```

It will generate a href link in my custom grid, but the problem when i click the link it always redirect me to admin dashboard, but if i click the href for new tab it redirects to the correct page